# Azure AppFabric Access Control Service Log Off

Tags: azure-appfabric, acs

I'm using Live Id and Google as IPs, but I don't know how to make the Log off button work.

Answer (score 2):

From http://acs.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/60691#1067602:

```
WSFederationAuthenticationModule fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;

try
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
}
finally
{
    fam.SignOut(true); 
}
```